# Is it possible to operate the Apache web server inside the iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ios

Use as a reverse proxy Apache web server worked on iOS, and I want to rewrite the content that appears on UIWebView.

Is it possible to operate the Apache web server inside the iOS app?

Comment: You... you want to install Apache? In an iPhone app?

Comment: I'm sure you can find a more lightweight way to serve web content to a UIWebView than Apache...